# Python - use .format to insert variables into a function

Tags: python, sqlite, string.format

I have a function that I need to call 13 times. So to save space and make it look more clean I want to use the following code to insert 13 variables into the function 13 times.

(Using * 1 rather than 13 so that the example is smaller/readable)

```
'INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(' + ''.join([cache_db.translate("{}")] *
1).format("hello") + ')'
```

My translate function replaces special characters with more unique special characters which you can see below. In that function '{' gets replaced by '.>.'
Thus my output ends up being `INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(".<..>.")`

The output that I'm expecting to get would be `INSERT INTO DATA VALUES("hello")`

My question is, does anyone know another way to pass in a variable properly? or if this actually is the correct way, would anyone know why this isn't working for me?
thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. Why not just use a for loop to call the function 13 times, and pass in one of the values on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: What does `cache_db.translate("{}")` do?

Comment: This looks like you're trying to use `format` to create an executable SQL statement. If so, abandon this approach now and read about SQL injection. Beyond that, I don't know what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thats a function of mine that replaces special characters with more unique special characters. The overall line does the same as  `'INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(' + ''.join(["{}"] * 1).format("hello") + ')'` With the output of `INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(hello)`

Comment: furthermore, use `'VALUES(?)', var` instead. And what does `* 1` do? This only looks like you're multiplying a string rather than inserting multiple variables

Comment: @roganjosh I am. Otherwise it becomes very lengthy. This approach would allow me to insert multiple variables in a short line or two.

Comment: I just edited my comment. You need to read about prepared statements, placeholders and SQL injection. Do this properly from the start; if you allow this approach to keep going, you really risk losing your database

Comment: @WillDaSilva I could use a loop, but I'm wanting to use .format instead. Mainly just because I'm curious if you can even use format to insert variables into the function

Comment: * 1 would give a result of `INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(hello)` If it were *2 with `.format("hello", "hi")` it would give a result of `INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(hello, hi)` @mangoHero1

Comment: @N.Thompson Ah I understand. Though it looks like the root cause of your problem is stemming from this `cache_db.translate()` function. how is this created or where was it `import`ed from?